# While running the below snippet, I am getting an error

Tags: python, tkinter

Many Thanks for your help! Now with this code, I am able to get the Text window. But, I am not able to get into the while loop.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
T = Text(root, height=2, width=30)
T.pack()
T.insert(END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
root.mainloop()
while(1):
    print("inside for loop")
    T.insert(END, "foo")
    T.see(END)
```

If I change the code as below,the text window is not appearing. Kindly request you to let me know how I can proceed, in here.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
T = Text(root, height=2, width=30)
T.pack()
T.insert(END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
while(1):
    print("inside for loop")
    T.insert(END, "foo")
    T.see(END)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jee11\workspace\hello\jeeva\hello\text_pad.py", line 14, in <module>
    T.insert(END,"TEST")
  File "C:\python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3266, in insert
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!text"

Comment: Fix code highlighting please.  Just add 4 spaces before your code and do indentation.

Answer (score 2):

For the future: please fix your code formatting (indentation matters!) and put Tracebacks into your question, not as an unformatted comment.

Concerning your error: it is caused because you are calling `T.insert` after `mainloop()`. You reach that point in the code after your mainloop is finished (e.g. if you close the window). Since there is no more Text area to insert something into, this strange error happens.

Aside from that, you are probably looking to do `if __name__=='__main__':`.